# Accepting blame for someone else?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, middos-character-traits, derech-eretz-manners

This is connected to my other question about [malicious compliance](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/132197/how-to-handle-situations-where-your-superior-has-insisted-you-do-something-that?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C46.1328), but a bit different. Imagine something goes wrong, and for whatever reason the blame falls on you even though it wasn't you, but you do know who it was.

Concrete examples:

- An important order wasn't made at work and a big contract falls through
- Someone's critical medications aren't ordered on time
- Wrong address provided and people end up missing an appointment and wasting time/money

**Is there a general principle regarding this?**

Comment: Isn't there a general principle somewhere that you are not obligated to make someone else pass before you, as an extension of Rabbi Akiva's decree that you don't have to give up your life for someone else?

Comment: It seems to me that rather than there being a single general principle here, what's allowed or meritorious or not would be highly dependant on a multitude of particular conditions of the situation, driving a constellation of different categories of Halachic or ethical principles.  This issue is demonstrated by your series of "What if" sub-questions. Do you have reason to believe that there is a unifying general principle that could constitute an on-point answer?

Comment: @IsaacMoses sincere apologies. As you can see, I'm still getting used to the way MY works. I'm not sure, that's why I asked. I was suspecting there might be a couple of different sefarim that deal with the specific question in the title, perhaps approaching from different sides and bringing different opinions, and that would be ok but give that it is not, I can only apologise for all the moderation work I've given you over the last few days. Shavua tov

Comment: @RabbiKaii No need to apologize! I think that it may be possible to sharpen this post to make it answerable, by asking if there is a general principle regarding such blame-taking rather than trying to get right to "what's the correct way to deal with this,"and  leaving out the complicating "what-if"s.

Comment: @IsaacMoses thanks for your very constructive feedback and all you do, we are not zoche